# Pass from a child Viewcontroller (Tab) to a view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller

I've got a tab ViewController(A) with 5 child view controllers(B) i want to pass from one of my child view controller to another view controller that i've got in my storyboard (C)

I made a button in a child view controller(B) and linked it to my (C) with push in my storyboard but when i click it this is what i get:

```
2015-07-04 16:04:36.641 LoginSampleFB[1447:74036] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d2c2c65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010cf5bbb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   UIKit                               0x000000010bd37d72 -[UIStoryboardPushSegue destinationContainmentContext] + 0
    3   UIKit                               0x000000010b7ead62 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 75
    4   UIKit                               0x000000010b8fc50a -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 467
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010b8fb8d9 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 522
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010b837958 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 735
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010b838282 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 682
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010b7fe541 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 246
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010b80bcdc _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 18265
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010b7e659c _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 2066
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d1f6431 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d1ec2fd __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 269
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d1eb934 __CFRunLoopRun + 868
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d1eb366 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    15  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010fab8a3e GSEventRunModal + 161
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010b7e98c0 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    17  LoginSampleFB                       0x000000010b4533ef main + 111
    18  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010db5a145 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `UINavigationControllers` as your tabs, and use the ViewControllers (B) as roots for these navigation controllers. Only that way can you perform a `push`. Otherwise you have to use a modal presentation which will cover partially or entirely your Tab bar controller.